# How to make a compound loop query with a join in MSQLAlchemy (Postgres) (Python)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Ok, please bear with me as I'm new to SQLAlchemy and Postgres. I have the following models: Lead, Keyword and User.

I have created a many to many relationship between leads and keywords like so:

```
keyword_identifier = db.Table(
    'keyword_identifier',
    db.Column('lead_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('leads.id')),
    db.Column('keyword_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('keywords.id'))
)
```

And in my User I have property called keywords, which is an array with keywords id in it.

Now I need to find all leads that are associated with the keywords' id present in the user.keywords list.

I have tried the following:

```
leads = Lead.query.join(keyword_identifier).join(Keyword).filter(keyword_identifier.c.lead_id.in_([k for k in u.keywords]))
```

Which brings only 2 results (I know that only one of the keywords have been associated with more than 2000 leads, so definitely not correct).

I have also tried:

```
for keyword_id in user.keywords:
    leads = Lead.query.join(keyword_identifier).join(Keyword).filter(keyword_identifier.c.lead_id == keyword_id)
```

But that's not bringing the right results either.

Can anyone recommend what would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified a mini example with the same database layout: A book is connected to one user (one to many), and a book has many words, and words can appear in multiple books (many to many). To get all the words for all books connected to a user, use this query:

```
Word.query.join(Word, Book.words).filter(Book.user_id==1).all()
```

So to translate it to your example it would be something like:

```
Lead.query.join(Lead, Keyword.leads).filter(Keyword.user_id==1234).all()
```

Full example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, BaseQuery

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    books = db.relationship('Book', backref='user')

class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    words = db.relationship('Word', secondary='book_to_word_junction', lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('book', lazy=True))

class Word(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

keyword_identifier = db.Table(
    'book_to_word_junction',
    db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id')),
    db.Column('word_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('word.id'))
)

db.create_all()

def add_db_samples():
    dummy_data = {
        'user1@email.com': {
            'harry potter': ['yer', 'a', 'wizard', 'herry', 'no', 'way', 'hagrid'],
            'egg cookbook': ['a', 'recipe', 'for', 'scrambled', 'eggs', 'no', 'really', 'yummy', 'eggs']
        },
        'user2@email.com': {
            'da vinci code': ['some', 'action', 'some', 'romance']
        }
    }


    for email in dummy_data:
        user = User()
        for title in dummy_data[email]:
            book = Book(title=title)
            for word_name in dummy_data[email][title]:
                word = Word.query.filter_by(name=word_name).first()
                if not word:
                    word = Word(name=word_name)
                book.words.append(word)
                db.session.add(word)
                db.session.commit()
            user.books.append(book)
        db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

add_db_samples()

print(Word.query.join(Word, Book.words).filter(Book.user_id==1).all())
```

Edit:

regarding your comment, you use `in_()` as you'd normally do in the filtering step:

```
Word.query.join(Word, Book.words).filter(Book.user_id.in_([1,2])).all()

Lead.query.join(Lead, Keyword.leads).filter(Keyword.user_id.in_([1, 2])).all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only thing that you're missing here is that instead of using a single id, I'd like to use an list of ids like so: `Keyword.user_id==[1, 2, 3, 4]`